# MFC: Confusion in an ON_COMMAND function?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, mfc

Alright, so here's this function

```
 
.
.
ON_COMMAND (ID_COLOR_RED, OnColor)
ON_COMMAND (ID_COLOR_GREEN, OnColor) 
ON_COMMAND (ID_COLOR_BLUE, OnColor)
.
.
. 
void CMainWindow::OnColor ()
{
    UINT nID = (UINT) LOWORD (GetCurrentMessage ()->wParam);
    m_nCurrentColor = nID _ ID_COLOR_RED;
}
```

So, in here the LOWORD of wParam of CurrentMessage is supposed to contain the Message's ID, that's okay, but what does  m_nCurrentColor = nID _ ID_COLOR_RED; means? The m_nCurrentColor can be 0,1, or 2 for red, green, or blue respectively...
So first we convert the Message's ID to UINT in first statement, but what are we trying to do in the second one with  m_nCurrentColor = nID _ ID_COLOR_RED?
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Unless you define the IDs by yourself instead of relying in the Resource files, you cannot guarantee the the Resource Editor will not screw up the IDs. For example, if you have ID_COLOR_RED= 10000,  ID_COLOR_GREEN=10001, ID_COLOR_BLUE=10001, things will be fine; but if the Editor changes the numeric symbol of ONLY ONE and your code will be broken for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what *that* code does. Primarily because `m_nCurrentColor = nID _ ID_COLOR_RED` won't compile. You have an underscore (`_`) between `nID` and `ID_COLOR_RED`. That doesn't mean anything to the compiler. Did you mean to type a minus sign (`-`), instead?

But more generally, the [`ON_COMMAND` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5f1bcxd.aspx) is used to process `WM_COMMAND` messages. The macro takes two parameters:

- `id`, which is the command ID
- `memberFxn`, which is the name of the message-hander function to which the command is mapped

It looks like you've got that all set up. All three command IDs (red, green, and blue) are being handled by the same `OnColor` function.

So let's look at the documentation for the [`WM_COMMAND` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647591.aspx). It says that the meaning of the `wParam` and `lParam` parameters depends on the source of the message. They have different meanings depending on whether the user selected an item from a menu, typed an accelerator keystroke, or a control is sending a notification message to its parent window.

I can't really tell from your question which of those `ID_COLOR_RED` (and its brethren) correspond to.
But it doesn't really matter. Either way, it *looks* like the code is attempting to set a member variable (`m_nCurrentColor`) that keeps track of the color that is currently selected by the user, based on the ID of the item that sent the last notification. If we assume that that's a *minus* sign, things start to come into focus a little bit:

What the code is doing is getting the ID of the item that's sending the message (`nID`), and subtracting the *first* value in the set from it (`ID_COLOR_RED`). That means if `nID` = `ID_COLOR_RED` then `m_nCurrentColor` will be 0.

If the values of `ID_COLOR_RED`, `ID_COLOR_GREEN`, and `ID_COLOR_BLUE` are *sequential* (and this is a big **if**, a good reason why you shouldn't write code like this), then if `nID` = `ID_COLOR_GREEN`, `m_nCurrentColor` will be 1. Likewise, if `nID` = `ID_COLOR_BLUE`, then `m_nCurrentColor` will be 2.

Comment: yeah, that's what I first thought that it was a misprint and it should be **minus** and not **underscore**, but I was just a bit confused..
thanx for help ;-)

Comment: @Razor: Yeah, but it's a misprint that won't compile. An underscore is not a valid symbol there. A minus is the only reasonable explanation I can come up with. Is this code from a book or something? I'm very skeptical of the coding practice it's teaching here. Like I said, it's not a good idea to rely on the fact that the IDs will forever remain sequential.

Comment: Yep, it was in a book, **Programming windows with MFC**, I also thought that minus is reasonable, but then I thought may be underscore means something else in MFC. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a continuation of my comment to the question.

For your example I would use the `ON_COMMAND_EX` macro with a `switch(nID)` inside the linked function. You wouldn't be worried if the ID of some option eventually changed.